# compatibility of Distributed transaction in SQL Server between

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distributed

Hi I just wanted to know is version of SQL server makes any differance in Compatibility of running Distributed transaction ?

If yes are distributed transaction in SQL Server between 
Server Set 1 [2005 & 2008 R2] 
Server Set 2 [2005 & 2012] are compatible to each other ? as I started the Dis tran in 2005 and it goes to either 2008 or 2012 and return to 2005? will this versions will make any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it makes no difference.

MSDTC is actually part of the Windows OS not SQL Server.
It is used by Windows itself.

So any compatibility issues come from OS differences.

Comment: ok great, but again one more problem my transaction is getting opened from Windows 2003,SQLserver2005 to Windows 2008,SQLserver2008/2012. this will work properly?

Comment: Should do... we have a mix of Windows 2008R2/2012/2012R2 and it alls runs smoothly. Same SQL Server versions though

Comment: No more then usual (I mean network permissions etc) if needed. Search on the internet if you get errors in the Event Log: they are well documented usually if you get any